# first application on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im begginer in RoR. help me please.
i use windows xp, ruby 1.9.2, sqlite 3.7.5
it r my steps for creating new.

---

1. install ruby
2. gem install rails
3. rails new C:\tm\test
4. sqlite3.dll, sqlite3.exe
5. gem install sqlite3-ruby
6. in database.yml:

   development:
   adapter: sqlite3
   dbfile: db/test.db
7. C:\tm\test>sqlite3 -init db.sql test.db
8. rails generate model Article
9. rails generate controller Article
10. in test\app\controllers\article_controller.rb:
    class ArticleController < ApplicationController
    scaffold :article
    end
11. rails server
    in Firefox http://localhost:3000/article

and have trouble on page:
ArgumentError 
No database file specified. Missing argument: database
but i must seeinterface for work with table

in cmd after i see:
ArgumentError (No database file specified. Missing argument: database):

---

in cmd after:
rails generate scaffold Article Article

---

i spend this:
Missing type for attribute 'Article'.
Example: 'Article:string' where string is the type.
help me please

Answer (score 4):

It's now `database` in YML, not `dbfile` anymore. Try with the following yml in `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.db
```

Here is a the guide to configure the database on [rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database).

Comment: Make sure that your sqlite3 database is in `C:\tm\test\db`.

Comment: change the `database.yml` as I described.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is the correct one. If you are scraping your code and need a test start off doing something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# Hyra Power
# 11/24/15

require 'active_record'

# ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)
# ActiveRecord::Base.colorize_logging = false

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "sqlite3",
    :database  => ":memory:"
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do

    create_table :pages do |table|
        table.column :url, :string, :null => false
        table.column :title, :string
        table.column :content_type, :string
        table.column :last_modified, :datetime
        table.column :error, :string
    end

    create_table :links do |table|
        table.column :from_page_id, :integer, :null => false
        table.column :to_page_id, :integer, :null => false
        table.column :count, :integer

    end

end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :links
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :page
end
```

Test this script and then move on from there. Hope this helps anyone new.

Answer (score -1):

i used: rake db: migrate.
and i see this:

---

rake aborted!
No database file specified. Missing argument: database

Comment: BTW you should edit your question if you have more information. The argument is missing, because in the `database.yml` you have `dbfile` instead of `database`.